# Get the type of List items looping through PropertyDescriptorCollection

Tags: c#, properties, propertydescriptor

Looping through properties of a generic type `T`, I'd like to know if `T` happens to be a `List` then what type of items does that list contain.

```
PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
       if (prop.PropertyType.Name.Equals("List`1"))
       ???
```

I can detect if type is a `List` using the above code but then how can I get the type of list items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the generic arguments use `GetGenericArguments` method, it will return an array of types, you can just get the first type which is the type of generic argument of your list:

```
var type = prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

Also instead of comparing names to check property type I would suggest this way:

```
if(prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
   prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
```